# Problem when graphing a recursive function/sequence.

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

Graph the following statement: count by two n times starting from three.

$a_n=a_{n-1}+2,a_0=3$

$a=2n+3$

---

| $a_1=a_{1-1}+2$ | $a_2=a_{2-1}+2$ | $a_3=a_{3-1}+2$ | $a_4=a_{4-1}+2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $a_1=a_0+2$ | $a_2=a_1+2$ | $a_3=a_2+2$ | $a_4=a_3+2$ |
| $a_1=3+2$ | $a_2=3+2+2$ | $a_3=3+2+2+2$ | $a_4=3+2+2+2+2$ |
| $a_1=5$ | $a_2=7$ | $a_3=9$ | $a_4=11$ |

```
0   1   2   3 ...
3 + 2 + 2 + 2 ...
3   5   7   9 ...
```

Assuming my analysis doesn't have multiple interpretations, however if so, any other perspectives are welcome, what would be the right way of graphing this entire analysis?

I went to https://www.mathway.com/ to graph both, the recursive and explicit froms of the same analysis and to my surprise I got two different lines.

After graphing the explicit form, I got a y-intercept of 3. However, after graphing the recursive form, I got a y-intercept of 2.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: As plain language could mean anything, please, ask your teacher to clarify which is the intended sequence to plot and tell us here which was the proper figures...

Comment: @Brethlosze I guess my question is why am I getting two different results from two equivalent notations? As far as I am concerned, every explicit equation can be expressed recursively. The statement is very simple: count by two as far as you want starting from three.

Comment: It is simply y=2x+3, plot with x integer (x=0,1,2...)

Comment: @Brethlosze then what is wrong with the recursive approach? Every problem can be solved recursively. I guess my point here is there seems to be a contradiction here.

Comment: No contradictions, you are simply starting at different values. Whatever you do, the first value *must* be 3.

Answer (score 1):

You must start from $y=3$, and the equation is $y=2x+3$ with $x$ integer $= 0,1,2...$

In WolframAlpha, for the first 10 terms, the graph is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=discrete%20plot%20f%20%3D%202x%2B3%20for%200%20%3C%20x%20%3C%3D%209).

[image]

Comment: OK lets put it this way, how can I get the same graph as above by using a recursive approach as mention in the problem. Both approaches should yield the same output. y = 2x + 3 is an explicit approach yielding a different result from the recursive one. And this is exaclty the issue at hand. How can I construct a recursive approach that matches the graph above?

Comment: $y=2x+1, x=1,2,...$ and $y=2x+3, x=0,1,...$ are completely equivalent, though symbolically different. You only must take care on the fact that the first term must be 3, whatever you decide to write